# Excel 2010 AddIn not loaded when Excel-Workbook opened with double click

Tags: excel, load, vsto, add-in

I wrote a Add-In for Excel 2010. It works fine if I open Excel from Start menu. But just if I double click on a Excel Workbook, the AddIn can not be loaded. I checked it in `ThisAddIn.cs`, the method `InternalStartup()` has not been involved. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

But opening file from command line "excel.exe table1.xlsx" works!

Comment: Check [Excel 2010 + COM add-in + Windows 7 preview pane = issue?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/fb72e113-c65c-4d79-8188-d3bb548939cc/) Is this your case?

Comment: Are you opening the file from the windows explorer or say from `Desktop`?

Comment: Both, I tried to open the file from desktop and the windows explorer.

Comment: Windows 7 preview pane works too! Just opening file from windows explorer and desktop don't work!

Comment: to my knowledge, no solution exists so far.

Comment: I have the same problem here , even when I check if my add-in is already in the add-in excel list  I found it !!! but it doesn't load when opening an already exiting Excel file