# VSTO Add-In Not Loading When Excel File Opened and Excel Already Running

Tags: vb.net, excel, vsto

I've created a VSTO Excel 2010 add-in that loads no matter where I run Excel from, whether the workbook is new or an already existing file.

The issue I'm having is that the add-in won't load when Excel is already running and I try to open a pre-existing workbook. If I go to Options -> Add-Ins, the add-in is listed in the Inactive Application Add-Ins.

One thing I notice is that when I open the existing workbooks, the loading window (shown in the image) doesn't run. Is there a setting to force a specific loading type?

[image: Excel Load File]

Note: I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978625/excel-2010-addin-not-loaded-when-excel-workbook-opened-with-double-click) post, but am not sure if it's the same issue, and don't see a solution.

Ideas?

Comment: Do you mean when you open another workbook it makes the addin inactive?

Comment: The add-in does not activate in the other workbook. 

Ex. If I open WkBk A, the add-in loads. If I then open WkBk B, a file named "Hello", for instance, then the add-in does not load. WkBk A will still have the add-in, however.

Comment: Do you get any error? Try enabling VSTO error by following these steps http://www.scinaptic.com/support/0053.html

Comment: Followed the instructions and it actually solved my problem. No errors appeared. Is there a way to adjust this setting programmatically in VB or C# .NET?

Comment: Sorry, what setting needs to be done programmatically?If it is different from above question please raise it as a different question

Comment: The setting described in the article you sent me: "VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS".

Comment: I wouldnt enable this for end user. But you can find a way in C# to set environment variables.